# form on this page has more than 1000 fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I have database on my localhost when I tried to export database it gave me this error

> Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields. on submission,
>   some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars
>   configuration.

so I have changed `max_input_vars = 1000` to  `max_input_vars = 10000`
now I am able to download the database but it is taking lot of time to import on server and also it might be corrupt my database.

is there any other option to get my database working? I have around 450 tables and some tables have around 4000-5000 entries

I am working on windows 7 with xammp server and I have created this database for magento website.

Comment: You have a table with 1000 columns? I think you need to look at normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet- nor a 'form'

Comment: Your question has exactly nothing to do with [tag:mysql] or [tag:localhost], and the error message makes it perfectly clear that it does have to do with [tag:php], [tag:html], and [tag:forms]. Don't tag indiscrminately, and do provide relevant tags. It is in your own interest.

Answer (score 1):

**This is 100% working**

First find to *max_input_vars* in php.ini file
and change to:

```
;max_input_vars = 1000
```

to

```
max_input_vars = 1000
```

This is working fine in know more [please visit video link](https://youtu.be/kUyOC2gfr8M).

Answer (score 0):

The following was the solution for me :

First of, be sure that you are editing the right `php.ini` file. To do that you can check what it is with `phpinfo()`.

Then restart php to reload `php.ini`, depending on how you installed it, it could be done like that :

`brew services restart php72`

Restart apache as well to be sure :

`sudo apachectl -k restart`

Then put the following statement in a test.php file :

`echo ini_get('max_input_vars');` and check it.

At this point you will see it is correctly updated.

If you still have phpmyadmin showing error after that, you should then hard refresh your phpmyadmin page : it can be done with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on a Mac.

The reason for this is that phpmyadmin's local javascript file is getting passed the value of `max_input_vars` from php and is responsible for deciding to display the error or not. So if the javascript local file isn't updated for caching reasons for example, then you just have to refresh it and problem gone : )

Answer (score -1):

You should provide more information about what system you are on and the method you tried to export the database, otherwise answers can't be specific.

mysqldump is what you need for exports.

On Linux (and probably on Apple computers too) you can simply use:

```
mysqldump -u YOUR_USER -p YOUR_DATABASE > DESIRED_FILE_NAME.sql
```

mysqldump should be also be available for Windows.